# c# jSON.net - unable to parse deserialized string - string does not contain definition for x

Tags: c#, json

I have a jSON string representing a start and end time, which I am trying to deserialize in c# in order to work out the timespan.

The jSON string is built as follows:

```
private string getTimes(int user)
{
    string jSON = "";
    string x = "&quot;";
    switch(user)
    {
        case 1:
            jSON = "{'startTime':08:00,'endTime':'16:00'}".Replace("'",x);
            break;
        case 2:
            jSON = "{'startTime':09:00,'endTime':'17:00'}".Replace("'", x);
            break;
        case 3:
            jSON = "{'startTime':12:00,'endTime':'20:00'}".Replace("'", x); ;
        break;
    }
    jSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jSON);
    return jSON;
}
```

and it returns a string (checked this in `Context.Response.Write`) like:

```
"{"startTime":12:00,"endTime":20:00}"
```

When I call `getTimes` (`int user` supplied via a dropdownlist selected value) I get an error: "'string' does not contain a definition for 'startTime'"

My code for calling `getTimes` is:

```
int user = int.Parse(ddlUser.SelectedValue);
    string timesInJSON = getTimes(user);

    var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(timesInJSON);
    DateTime dtStart = Convert.ToDateTime(results.startTime);
    DateTime dtEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(results.endTime);
```

I'm confused as I thought it should deserialize the jSON and give me the right result? What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: you're missing quotes in the start time values

Comment: It's `Timespan` and not `DateTime`. Why are you creating json manually? Why you deseriaize into `dynamic` instead of `JsonObject` or flat model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to serialize a string?
You serialize objects to get a string.

```
private string getTimes(int user)
{
    string jSON = "";
    string x = "&quot;";
    switch(user)
    {
        case 1:
            jSON = "{'startTime':08:00,'endTime':'16:00'}".Replace("'",x);
            break;
        case 2:
            jSON = "{'startTime':09:00,'endTime':'17:00'}".Replace("'", x);
            break;
        case 3:
            jSON = "{'startTime':12:00,'endTime':'20:00'}".Replace("'", x); ;
        break;
    }
    //jSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jSON);
    return jSON; //<-- already serialised
}
```

Typical usage (TimeSpans might be betterfor your situation though instead of DateTimes) ...

```
var foo = { starttime = Datetime.UtcNow, endTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1) };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
var bar = JsonConvert.DeSerializeObject(json);
```

Comment: I think you would also need to remove the horrendous html entity escaping in there. As it is with the quotes being replaced by `&quot;` its not going to be valid json I'd think.

Comment: Thank you. So yes it was this, missing quotes around the startTime value, and also for the replacement of ' with " I needed to make x a char and make the .replace `.Replace("'", x.ToString())` - which Chris has just mentioned above :). Also I do need the times not the timespan (although i need the timespan elsewhere too.)

Comment: @Dave: Don't construct your JSON manually at all. Use the methods War puts at the end to construct an object and then serialise it. You have a JSON library, make use of it!

Comment: doing that would likely result in invalid JSON yes, those last 3 lines in my answer should help clarify that though if you run them and look at the results you can see how well formatted JSON looks.

Comment: It's probaly a good rule of thumb to work with objects until you need to return to the client some result, try to stay away from building JSON strings yourself, just build an object that looks like what you want and serialise it with ... var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

Comment: yes, thanks... ultimately i won't be making the JSON manually- i am sort of doing a quick and dirty proof of concept at the moment. eventually the individual user's start and end times would come from a database and then I'd only need JSON (which I'd construct as War advises) when sending it to my mobile app via a web service. turns out it was very dirty.. thanks for the help guys i appreciate it!